# Google charts how to get crosshairs to remain after selection in React

Tags: reactjs, charts

I've searched extensively for this issue here and haven't been able to figure this out. I have a google chart in my app and have a callback function in place to get the details of each point when selected so that I can update a modal to display more info elsewhere.

However, when I have this callback activated and the user clicks the item, the crosshairs do not stay. When I don't have the callback active, they do remain and I get a nice small circle around the selected point like this:

[image of crosshairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXDw1.png)

Here are the chartevent details I have in place which are working to return the details of the point. Is the chartevent option perhaps overriding a crosshair default?

Grateful for any advice.

Cheers.

```
   const chartEvents = [{
     eventName: "select",
     options: {
       tooltip: {
         trigger: "selection"
       }
     },
     callback: ({ chartWrapper }) => {
       const chart = chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection()[0].row;
       this.setState((prevState) => ({ selectedMonth: chart }))
       this.setChangedMonth()
     }
   }]
```